# Change script from start onclick to onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to change this script so that the animation starts once the page has loaded instead of when the div is clicked on.

Any suggestions on how I could do this would be much appreciated.

Here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".marqueeElement").last().addClass("last");
$(".mholder").each(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $(this).find(".marqueeElement").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css("top", i);
        i += $this.height();
    });
});

$('.mholder').click(function() {
    var countScrolls = $('.mholder .marqueeElement').length;

    for (var i=0; i < countScrolls; i++) {
       doScroll($('.mholder .marqueeElement:nth-child(' + i + ')'));
    }
});
});

function doScroll($ele) {
var top = parseInt($ele.css("top"));
if (top < -60) { //bit arbitrary!
    var $lastEle = $ele.closest('.mholder').find(".last");
    $lastEle.removeClass("last");
    $ele.addClass("last");
    var top = (parseInt($lastEle.css("top")) + $lastEle.height());
    $ele.css("top", top);
}
$ele.animate({
    top: (parseInt(top) - 60)
}, 80, 'linear', function() {
    doScroll($(this))
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the code inside the `.ready()` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".marqueeElement").last().addClass("last");
$(".mholder").each(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $(this).find(".marqueeElement").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css("top", i);
        i += $this.height();
    });
});

    var countScrolls = $('.mholder .marqueeElement').length;

    for (var i=0; i < countScrolls; i++) {
       doScroll($('.mholder .marqueeElement:nth-child(' + i + ')'));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `'.mholder'` is the selector for your div, just get rid of the click handler - i.e. change from:

```
$('.mholder').click(function() {
    var countScrolls = $('.mholder .marqueeElement').length;

    for (var i=0; i < countScrolls; i++) {
       doScroll($('.mholder .marqueeElement:nth-child(' + i + ')'));
    }
});
```

to

```
var countScrolls = $('.mholder .marqueeElement').length;

for (var i=0; i < countScrolls; i++) {
   doScroll($('.mholder .marqueeElement:nth-child(' + i + ')'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the most easiest way is to put at the end of the on ready function the following (after you bind the click event):

```
$('.mholder').click()
```